# ASP.Net MVC strongly typed partial views and inherited properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, inheritance, properties, partial

I'm building a web-application with MS MVC 3 and have run into an issue, probably due to a hole in my understanding of model-binding.

Firstly, I have a fairly standard model (irrelevant stuff omitted for brevity, names changed to protect the privacy of innocent objects):

```
public class ModelBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

 public class Order : ModelBase
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product : ModelBase
{
    public int OrderId { get; set;}
}
```

For displaying and editing these, I have a View strongly typed to the Order class, containing a Partial View which is strongly typed to the Product class. The top of the partial view looks like this:

```
@model Product

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderId)
//loads of actual editable properties
```

I insert the partial into the main view like this:

```
@Html.Partial("EditorTemplates/Product", Model.Products.First())
```

...and when the view is rendered in the browser, the "Id" hidden input contains the Id of the Order, not the Id of the Product that I expect and need :(

What am I missing? Can it be fixed without changing the structure of the model and views?

Comment: Looks ok, how do you know for sure that the Id is the order?  Is the OrderId displaying properly?

Comment: The OrderId does display properly, and it's the same value being displayed in the Id field. I guess I don't know for sure that it's the value coming from Order, though, as the value is also present as part of the request url (/Orders/Step2/10 where 10 is the Order Id). Could it be this value that's overwriting the Id field?

Comment: You can confirm through the DB whether or not the orderid is the same as the id for this record?

Comment: In my specific test case, the Order Id is 10 and the Product Id is 3. I'm getting 10 in both fields. There is no Product with an Id of 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On changing my test project I can confirm that

/Home/Index?id=33

or

/Home/Index/33

DOES overwrite the model value. Can you remove this parameter from the url?

Comment: That's it! The binder is putting route values into the fields, in a case-insensitive way and overwriting the value from the model. I added a new route in Global.Asax for the Order-editing part of the application, like this:
`"Orders/{StepNo}/{OrderId}"` ...and now my values are preserved since it's no longer matching the default routevalue {id} to my "Id" field. All it took was the new route and some new names for my action parameters. No structural changes needed and MVC doesn't have a problem with inheritance like I first feared. Thanks a bunch for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to change the structure.

You could either put the partial content into the main view, or strongly type the partial to the Order not the Product, or construct the hidden field using Html.Hidden(). MVC is not putting the whole path to the item in the HiddenFor relative to the model in your post action.

ie. In the html you would see

```
<input type="hidden" name="Id" />
```

but you really want

```
<input type="hidden" name="Products[0].Id" />
```

in order to distinguish the fields and items.

---

The above problem still remains when you attempt to POST two different hidden inputs with the same name, however I also wrote a test project that works as far as the client.

Hope this helps:

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Order order = new Order() { Id = 1 };
            order.Products = new List<Product>() { new Product() { Id = 3, OrderId = 1 } };
            return View("Order",order);
        }
```

Models

```
public class Order : IdentityBase
    {
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product : IdentityBase
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
    }

 public class IdentityBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Order

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Order</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        @foreach (MvcApplication1.Models.Product product in Model.Products)
        {
            <div class="product">
                @Html.Partial("Product", product)
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Partial View

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Product

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderId)
```

Client Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Order</title>    
</head>    
<body>    
    <div>    
       <input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="1" />    
       <div class="product"> 
                <input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="3" />    
                <input id="OrderId" name="OrderId" type="hidden" value="1" />    
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Here is where we gained this insight:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Comment: I understand how to construct controls for collections, but that's not what I want to do. It's just the first element that I'm trying to edit. As you can probably tell from the partial's path, I'm looking to re-use the product edit partial throughout the application.
Trying to use `@Html.Hidden("Id", Model.Id)` produced the same (wrong) result as HiddenFor. Doing `@Html.Hidden("P_Id", Model.Id)` gives the expected value, however, so clearly the right value is present in the partial view, but is simply being overwritten at some point.

Comment: What is the scope of your Html form? Is it possible you are posting back two elements with name "Id"? You can check this in the html of the page or in the form value collection in your POST action.

Comment: I'm not making a POST (yet). The value is wrong on the client side after receiving the response to the GET request. I am able to output the correct value to the client if I change the name of the "Id" field to something else, but if I don't, it appears that the value is being overwritten at some point in the process of putting together the view. Either the Id of the wrong model, the Order, is being added to the field in the partial, or the Id in the request url somehow finds its way into my field, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. The HiddenFor naming convention is not aware of the depth of a partial view, we have had similar problems. I think we had some success with something like
HiddenFor(m=>m.Parent[m.Parent.IndexOf(m)].Id)
or similar, but I'll have to knock up a test project to check

Comment: I'd rather it wasn't aware, tbh. I intend to re-use the partial view in situations where the Product to be edited isn't the child of an Order or even included in a list on a parent object. The Product objects should be able to stand on their own, but if I want that to work, I need to figure out how to prevent the data of other objects from seeping into the view I designed for the Product.